# Laravel - Inserting multiple items using one-to-many relationship

Tags: php, laravel

Is it possible to insert multiple values through a one-to-many relationship, so that the multiple values are saved with the foreign key.

So for example: I have an array of 'contributers' which a user can select to add to a project - upon saving I want these contributers to be referenced to the *just* saved project.

Trying the code below (the array is coming from $_POST['contributers'] which are checkboxes) - it saves the data, but doesn't attach the foreign key. I want to avoid having to use a loop and just be able to bulk insert all of these

```
$this->project->find($project->id)
      ->contributers()
       ->insert(Input::only('contributers')['contributers']);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `createMany` method ([link to source](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/HasOneOrMany.php#L331-L346))

```
$project = $this->project->find($project->id);
$project->contributers()->createMany(Input::get('contributers'));
```

I also propose a small refactoring : one action per line and use of `Input::get()` instead of `Input:only()`, which is designed for other use cases.

Comment: Thanks, but I receive the following "Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::sync()". Also, I might be misunderstanding it but doesn't the docs say sync is for a many-to-many relationship?

Comment: Answer edited. Sorry, I had not completely read your question. You want to create new contributers, right ? Or do you want just edit the foreign key of existing contributers ?

Comment: that did the job, thanks! I did try using createMany before but must have been in a different context as it's now working.